# AMP: use route info from url

Tags: amp-html

For a URL `/products/123`, can we grab and use that `123` from the URL to fetch and display the corresponding data?
If I understand correctly, making this dynamic allows handling user clicks on related products with a `setState`, allowing one to reuse the template.

Comment: why not just server render the initial state and go from there?

Comment: @Scriptonomy: thanks for asking. Advantages of having this ability from AMP: * a single static asset could be used across the different items. I'm hoping this would facilitate combining AMP with a serverless architecture. * skip another page load when navigating to a different item. * keep logic dynamic to reuse in the PWA, where I fear hard navigation would result in loss of application state (`AMP.setState` stuff).

Comment: Related: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/issues/11601

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query parameters can be accessed using [AMP variable substitution](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md#query-parameter), which is supported by the `amp-list` component. In your case you could provide a product id via query parameter:

`/products?product=123456`

...and then use amp-list to render the product details:

```
<amp-list src="https://foo.com/list.json?product=QUERY_PARAM(product)">
  ...
</amp-list>
```

Comment: Here's the link: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/main/docs/spec/amp-var-substitutions.md